# log4j in Netbeans doesn't works in installed application

Tags: java, netbeans, log4j

I'm using log4j from the netbeans ide correctly. Now that I'm testing logging from the installed application, anything works.

In the project I have a wrapper module WrapperLog4j (com.aws.log4j) where I put in the log4j wrapped jar file, and the log4j.xml config file in com.aws.log4j package.

In addition, I have an app.conf file to define jdkhome, jvm option, userdir, etc....
The default_userdir="${HOME}/AwsSuite" has setted right, and has the

C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\AwsSuite value when I execute the installed application.

In the log4j.xml, for the file appender has the value:

All this is working fine when I execute the application from the IDE. In the ProjectFolder/build/testuserdir/var/log is the file awssuite.log required for logging.

I try to changing ${netbeans.user} for ${user.home}, defining new jvm variable in -J-DMyVariable=${HOME}/AwsSuite for use it in log4j.xml as ${MyVariable} in the appender file parameter, but nothing.

Any suggestions?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: log4j will complain at runtime if something went wrong by loading the properties file, did you try starting the app from the terminal just to see if anything get printed?????

Comment: @ΦXoce 웃 Пepeúpa I start the app as you suggest, but any error is showed.

Comment: Please, any tip to solve this issue?